# Fail2ban not banning ip address

Tags: ubuntu, security, iptables, fail2ban

I installed `fail2ban` on a Ubuntu 20.04 server. I've followed some articles on how to configure it but it doesn't work. I've made 10 incorrect login attempts and still didn't get banned.

`/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`:

```
[sshd]

enabled  = true
port     = 27485
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 3
bantime = 4w
findtime = 1d
```

`/var/log/auth.log`:

```
sudo:  user : TTY=pts/3 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail -f /var/log/auth.log
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by user(uid=0)
sshd[23907]: Connection closed by authenticating user user 111.1.1.1 port 8825 [preauth]
sshd[23909]: Connection closed by authenticating user user 111.1.1.1 port 8827 [preauth]
sshd[23911]: Connection closed by authenticating user user 111.1.1.1 port 8828 [preauth]
sshd[23913]: Connection closed by authenticating user user 111.1.1.1 port 8829 [preauth]
sshd[23915]: Connection closed by authenticating user user 111.1.1.1 port 8830 [preauth]
```

What did I do wrong here? I've ran `systemctl status fail2ban` and it is running. I've also `restarted` it after saving the config.

Comment: what does the fail2ban logging say? i.e. `journalctl -u fail2ban` or check for a log file in `/var/log`

Comment: Thanks for helping me out @TomH. I've checked both files and there wasn't anything wrong. the journalctl command just showed that the fail2ban has started and the log file is the one I posted above. /log is a directory containing auth.log

Comment: it looks like the failed attempts are not showing in the `/var/log/auth.log`... ? if so, then it's not fail2ban problem, its that sshd is not logging failed attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide more from your `/var/log/auth.log`.

I tried a local test with a non-existing user, and this is what I see in the log (on ubuntu 20.04 instance)

```
Oct 23 16:23:48 vps-34 sshd[35253]: Invalid user adminxxx from 123.123.123.123 port 35382
Oct 23 16:23:50 vps-34 sshd[35253]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Oct 23 16:23:50 vps-34 sshd[35253]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=123.123.123.123
Oct 23 16:23:52 vps-34 sshd[35253]: Failed password for invalid user adminxxx from 54.38.78.234 port 35382 ssh2
Oct 23 16:23:55 vps-34 sshd[35253]: Connection closed by invalid user adminxxx 54.38.78.234 port 35382 [preauth]
```

Obviously, unless sshd is logging failures, fail2ban can't pick that up...

Possibly, you have ssh-agent, or some other method which is automatically logging you in to the server...

can you try something like:

```
ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=password -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o  ControlPath=none example.com
```

(To force it to use password auth) and tail the log at the same time:

```
# tail -f  /var/log/auth.log
```

Comment: I've posted more from my `/var/log/auth.log` . Thats the only log I got. I really don't know how to do the `ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=Password ` command. I entered it and the screen got stucked at the command and didn't output anything.

Comment: I just realized you're about to reach 10k. I upvoted and accepted your answer :) How would I solve the problem though? I don't have the same log as yours

Comment: Thanks for noticing!

Comment: re the answer. So the problem seems to be that sshd isn't logging your failures to login. I'm guessing that is because either something else is blocking the login, or that the login is successful.